# How to connect emulator to redux-saga-firebase app

Tags: javascript, firebase, redux-saga-firebase

I'm trying to set up the emulator for firebase.  My app is built with https://redux-saga-firebase.js.org/ The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-emulator#2) says to add code like this to point the app to the emulator.  Or maybe it's [these directions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_and_prototype)?

```
  const db = firebaseApp.firestore();

  // ADD THESE LINES
  if (window.location.hostname === "localhost") {
    console.log("localhost detected!");
    db.settings({
      host: "localhost:8080",
      ssl: false
    });
  }
```

Here is my file, where firebase is set up.  Notice, `firebaseApp` is initialized differently.

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import '@firebase/firestore';
import ReduxSagaFirebase from 'redux-saga-firebase';
import { FIREBASE_CONFIG } from '../keys';

const config = FIREBASE_CONFIG;

export const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config);

export const rsf = new ReduxSagaFirebase(firebaseApp);
```

I add this, but it still points to production data.

```
if (window.location.hostname === "localhost") {
    rsf.settings({
        host: "localhost:8080",
        ssl: false
    });
}
```

I have also tried this.

```
let config = FIREBASE_CONFIG;

if (window.location.hostname === "localhost") {
    config = {
      ...config,
      databaseURL: 'https://localhost:8080?ns=<<myProjectId>>',
    }
}
```

And this.

```
   if (location.hostname === "localhost") {
     firebaseApp.useEmulator("localhost", 8080);
   }
```

The emulators are running, but how do I connect my app?